# How to implement 'ThreadPoolExecutor' in Python?

Tags: multithreading, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, threadpoolexecutor

Actually, I have scraped the **'Nykaa Website'**. But Problem is that it's **taking around 10 days**, to fetch the complete data. Which is very **time-consuming**.

Basically, I want to **optimize or automate this Code**, so it takes the **least time**. Recently, I have learned about the concept of **'Threading' and 'ThreadPoolExecutor'**. So, **Threading will speed up our tasks, by running the requests concurrently.**

***Now, This is the Code, which I've tried to Implement***

```
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy import Request, FormRequest
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from w3lib.html import remove_tags
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
import json
import re
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from couponsscraper.loaders import ListingLoader
import time
import concurrent.futures


class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'nykaa_comla'
    custom_settings = {
        # "PROXY_ON": True,
        "HTTPCACHE_ENABLED": False,
        "CONCURRENT_REQUESTS": 4,
        "COOKIES_ENABLED": True,
        "AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED": True,
        "RETRY_TIMES": 5,
        "DOWNLOAD_DELAY": 1,
        "RETRY_HTTP_CODES": [500, 503, 504, 400, 401, 403, 405, 404, 408, 416, 456, 502, 429, 307]
    }

    headers = {
        # "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        # "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        # "accept-language": "tr-TR,tr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
        # "cookie": "bcookie=3a6db8c0-6226-4d67-9b3c-39ee6fb7002b; EXP_ADP_RV_REORDER=A; EXP_ADP_RV_SEGMENT=B; run=43; D_LST=1; D_PDP=1; _gcl_au=1.1.515177829.1644933995; _ga=GA1.2.1857014358.1644933996; _gid=GA1.2.1588295387.1644933996; d_info=1536_864; N_S_A_W=1; N_A_P=1; GPAY_INTENT=1; D_HOM=1; N_CMS=0; PHPSESSID=041dvmhr4r3nqj0mt051pid5q0; disableSmartLogin=true; SHOW_PREVIEW_INFO_PAGE=false; OLD_LISTING_FLOW=false; GC_PREVIEW_EXPERIMENT=true; NEW_PRE_CONFIRMATION=true; C_AUTH=false; NEW_PAYMENT_PAGE=false; VIEW_COUPON_EXPERIMENT=true; NEW_ORDERLISTING_PAGE=true; NEW_ORDERDETAIL_PAGE=false; AMCVS_FE9A65E655E6E38A7F000101%40AdobeOrg=1; s_cc=true; frontendSource=react; pro=false; head_data_react={}; form_key=FFGAZIZcYSy6guaw; s_nr=1644987663041-Repeat; countryCode=TR; storeId=nykaa; lux_uid=164502537781396625; AMCV_FE9A65E655E6E38A7F000101%40AdobeOrg=-432600572%7CMCIDTS%7C19039%7CMCMID%7C81426820227033618243066641334787189520%7CMCAAMLH-1645633715%7C6%7CMCAAMB-1645633715%7CRKhpRz8krg2tLO6pguXWp5olkAcUniQYPHaMWWgdJ3xzPWQmdj0y%7CMCOPTOUT-1645036115s%7CNONE%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CvVersion%7C4.5.2; SITE_VISIT_COUNT=85; s_nr365=1645030255086-Repeat; cto_bundle=yZ-Tl19IZXRJdEFwYmJiRFlKdEUyRnMwdTJSYU8xanJLMjklMkJFZTdkSk1rZ2lobHFpRFU1RXRvNTFFOW5LM0x0NXE4RCUyQlk0eW5hZHklMkI1bjFIODFPeiUyQlljNXlUWnJSNTglMkJINU5LR1h6NlBVSWNROVNqNHZyazFBeVhiYzR0RSUyRmNiemQlMkYlMkJQMktDYlRiZ1pFbUVORlZoWERKbzFRJTNEJTNE; TS017d4a61=01317c4d00f4b4ecb9729e778b9c17dcf4ff9e0bde970f7d1b21ba9c6b22be6412bd39ff683b78cec4d5d72fa884218be5d8643776; TS5e83d05f027=08d3514ca6ab2000f82ea30abe3eacc9f428099d8668cb41a92cd2d81928f740933aee4731fd569b083d5530361130005c7a54f3c04dfcf2867d258ecec44f2412921fab91b839896e317f4c2953ff0d9fb3c2db28b8cfda2319bf9176d7af9f; s_sq=fsnecommerceprod%3D%2526c.%2526a.%2526activitymap.%2526page%253DNykaa%2526link%253DHair%252520Removal%252520Tools%2525202%2526region%253Dcustom-scroll%2526pageIDType%253D1%2526.activitymap%2526.a%2526.c%2526pid%253DNykaa%2526pidt%253D1%2526oid%253Dfunctioncn%252528%252529%25257B%25257D%2526oidt%253D2%2526ot%253DDIV",
        # "referer": "https://www.nykaa.com/personal-care-appliances/c/1390?page_no=1&sort=popularity&eq=desktop&category_filter=1408,1412,1411,1543,6290,1405,1404,1517,41,43,44,1399,1400,1406",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.82 Safari/537.36",
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        start_urls = [
            {
                "url": [
                    "https://www.nykaa.com/app-api/index.php/products/list?category_filter=1408%2C1412%2C1411%2C1543%2C6290%2C1405%2C1404%2C1517%2C41%2C43%2C44%2C1399%2C1400%2C1406%2C1401&category_id=1390&client=react&filter_format=v2&page_no=1&platform=website&sort=popularity",
                    "https://www.nykaa.com/app-api/index.php/products/list?category_filter=8446%2C8452%2C8443%2C8444%2C8441%2C8445%2C8448%2C8397%2C8442%2C8394%2C8449%2C8453%2C8451%2C8395%2C8396%2C8398%2C8420%2C8426%2C8644%2C8421%2C8427%2C8423%2C14001%2C8422%2C8424%2C8436%2C8438%2C8437%2C8382%2C8383%2C8381%2C8380%2C8379%2C8400%2C8401%2C8392%2C8429%2C8430%2C8409%2C8410%2C8411%2C8432%2C8433%2C8434%2C8405%2C8407%2C8406%2C8403%2C8404&category_id=8377&client=react&filter_format=v2&page_no=1&platform=website&sort=popularity",
                    "https://www.nykaa.com/app-api/index.php/products/list?category_filter=242%2C240%2C2440%2C687%2C241%2C247%2C245%2C244%2C931%2C1995%2C228%2C235%2C237%2C233%2C234%2C231%2C236%2C239%2C6761%2C4140%2C232%2C229%2C220%2C249%2C263%2C254%2C250%2C251%2C253%2C5079%2C252%2C7008%2C267%2C268%2C4037%2C271%2C266%2C269%2C270%2C273%2C272%2C947%2C1513%2C1514%2C3819%2C3745%2C3749%2C3746%2C255%2C3277%2C257%2C256%2C260&category_id=12&client=react&filter_format=v2&page_no=1&platform=website&sort=popularity",
                    "https://www.nykaa.com/app-api/index.php/products/list?category_filter=2444%2C2048%2C361%2C362%2C364%2C363%2C2049%2C7007%2C316%2C319%2C2046%2C2040%2C320%2C2041%2C22630%2C317%2C1214%2C1222%2C2746%2C2045%2C2043%2C331%2C332%2C346%2C329%2C11111&category_id=24&client=react&filter_format=v2&page_no=1&platform=website&sort=popularity",
                    "https://www.nykaa.com/app-api/index.php/products/list?category_filter=13561%2C6790%2C1642%2C1645%2C326%2C13562%2C368%2C367%2C369%2C370%2C39%2C391%2C1654%2C9475%2C1647%2C690%2C1816%2C381%2C584%2C385%2C382%2C7466%2C371%2C377%2C374%2C1389%2C688%2C7010%2C396%2C1386%2C1640%2C663%2C1133%2C1660%2C662%2C290%2C7009%2C2086%2C14358&category_id=12930&client=react&filter_format=v2&page_no=1&platform=website&sort=popularity",
                    "https://www.nykaa.com/app-api/index.php/products/list?category_filter=9607%2C9606%2C9611%2C9608%2C9609%2C9613%2C9612%2C9610%2C9626%2C9627%2C9625%2C9624%2C9628%2C9631%2C9630%2C9632%2C9629%2C9582%2C9581%2C9567%2C9571%2C9584%2C9569%2C9566%2C9579%2C9576%2C9568%2C9634%2C9637%2C9636%2C9635&category_id=12930&client=react&filter_format=v2&page_no=1&platform=website&sort=popularity",
                    "https://www.nykaa.com/app-api/index.php/products/list?category_filter=14799%2C14801%2C14806%2C14805%2C14800%2C14803%2C14834%2C15013%2C15010%2C14802%2C14804%2C14807%2C14808%2C15009%2C14809%2C14828%2C14829%2C15357%2C15123%2C15124%2C14838%2C14839%2C14844%2C14840%2C14836%2C22633%2C14824%2C14820%2C14822%2C14819%2C14821%2C14823%2C15129%2C16966%2C16969%2C16964%2C16968%2C16970%2C15358%2C14846%2C14816%2C14813%2C14815%2C14814%2C14812%2C14817%2C14811%2C15126%2C15127%2C14848%2C14835%2C15125&category_id=14797&client=react&filter_format=v2&page_no=1&platform=website&sort=popularity",
                    "https://www.nykaa.com/app-api/index.php/products/list?category_filter=19868%2C19869%2C20421%2C19867%2C19864%2C1657%2C1656%2C1658%2C18549%2C18550%2C18547%2C19894%2C18548%2C18556%2C18555%2C18553%2C1620%2C18552%2C18554%2C2027%2C19878%2C19856%2C1614%2C19881%2C19876%2C19857%2C19875%2C1618%2C19879%2C19877%2C19870%2C18577%2C18575%2C18573%2C18698%2C18574%2C19872%2C18570%2C18697%2C18579%2C19871%2C18578%2C18569%2C18542%2C2020%2C18544%2C18543%2C18541%2C18551%2C18558%2C18561%2C18567%2C18559%2C18566%2C18560%2C18565%2C18564%2C18563%2C19859%2C19861%2C18562%2C19858%2C19860&category_id=671&client=react&filter_format=v2&page_no=1&platform=website&sort=popularity",
                    "https://www.nykaa.com/app-api/index.php/products/list?category_filter=1324%2C1323%2C328%2C1287%2C568%2C11028%2C1289%2C1548%2C1291%2C11029%2C1290%2C1288%2C11045%2C11216%2C11054%2C11047%2C11046%2C2803%2C11048%2C2801%2C2799%2C1294%2C1415%2C1297%2C1298%2C1293%2C1296%2C1295%2C1414%2C1413%2C1308%2C1307%2C7034%2C1316%2C1313%2C1314%2C1312%2C1311%2C1328%2C6543%2C1326%2C1329%2C1305%2C1303%2C1306%2C1304%2C1302%2C1301&category_id=9150&client=react&filter_format=v2&page_no=1&platform=website&sort=popularity",
                    "https://www.nykaa.com/app-api/index.php/products/list?category_filter=974%2C979%2C1235%2C975%2C962%2C971%2C970%2C18521%2C3126%2C18313%2C18319%2C18311&category_id=53&client=react&filter_format=v2&page_no=1&platform=website&sort=popularity"
                ],

            },

        ]  # LEVEL 1

        t1 = time.perf_counter()

        def download_urls(start_urls):
            for url in start_urls:
                for item in url.get('url'):
                    yield Request(
                        url=item,
                        callback=self.jump, headers=self.headers
                    )

        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            executor.map(download_urls, start_urls)

        t2 = time.perf_counter()

        print(f'Finished in {t2-t1} seconds')

    def jump(self, response):

        headers = {
            # "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
            # "cookie": "bcookie=3a6db8c0-6226-4d67-9b3c-39ee6fb7002b; EXP_ADP_RV_REORDER=A; EXP_ADP_RV_SEGMENT=B; run=43; D_LST=1; D_PDP=1; _gcl_au=1.1.515177829.1644933995; _ga=GA1.2.1857014358.1644933996; _gid=GA1.2.1588295387.1644933996; AMCVS_FE9A65E655E6E38A7F000101%40AdobeOrg=1; d_info=1536_864; s_cc=true; frontendSource=react; N_S_A_W=1; N_A_P=1; GPAY_INTENT=1; D_HOM=1; N_CMS=0; AMCV_FE9A65E655E6E38A7F000101%40AdobeOrg=-432600572%7CMCIDTS%7C19039%7CMCMID%7C81426820227033618243066641334787189520%7CMCAAMLH-1645555116%7C6%7CMCAAMB-1645555116%7CRKhpRz8krg2tLO6pguXWp5olkAcUniQYPHaMWWgdJ3xzPWQmdj0y%7CMCOPTOUT-1644957516s%7CNONE%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CvVersion%7C4.5.2; countryCode=TR; storeId=nykaa; lux_uid=164495373425081540; SITE_VISIT_COUNT=42; s_nr365=1644954403255-Repeat; cto_bundle=FmfdrF9IZXRJdEFwYmJiRFlKdEUyRnMwdTJacUclMkZESTVtbFJoeSUyRm9DeWFuZnNyUHB1Wmp6Mjd5aSUyRnpoJTJGUW9adHBvJTJGaDklMkZVU2JqeTBmUnNQNWRZUkFlZFdkU01HOUtFN1FVM2NqQ2hyJTJCSWNCRHVqWXVIYmxGSmtYalY1ZWVlNzhuOEFFeiUyRmJkYW0lMkY1eExpWTIlMkI5UWFVTk9xUSUzRCUzRA; s_sq=fsnecommerceprod%3D%2526c.%2526a.%2526activitymap.%2526page%253DNykaa%2526link%253DCategory%2526region%253Dfirst-filter%2526pageIDType%253D1%2526.activitymap%2526.a%2526.c%2526pid%253DNykaa%2526pidt%253D1%2526oid%253Dfunctioncn%252528%252529%25257B%25257D%2526oidt%253D2%2526ot%253DDIV; TS017d4a61=01317c4d00801f0f349c15b870e54bb5b073295e5cd3300ec6151f9df175201cd7088a4fddc721927b22edfb27519afe45b7706946; TS5e83d05f027=08d3514ca6ab200050d2f52481b8d6300143ac438c162c3b9a85f08eef7a692b65d0a08e95fa92ca08337d71c4113000d7f4a8888b3d70b89797c2274d4e26fe457de218890038f0d09704e9c58b3c0655ad652c93a0e031aa4d0ee666767637",
            # "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
            "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.82 Safari/537.36"
        }
        page = response.meta.get('page', 2)
        seen = False
        data = json.loads(response.body)['response']['products']
        for item in data:
            try:
                main = item['primary_categories']['l1']['name']
                sub = item['primary_categories']['l2']['name']
                child = item['primary_categories']['l3']['name']
                follow_url = item['product_url']
                yield Request(follow_url, callback=self.parse, meta={'main_cat': main, 'sub_cat': sub, 'child_cat': child}, headers=headers)
                seen = True
            except:
                pass

        if page == 2 or seen:
            headersa = {
                # "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
                # "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
                # "accept-language": "tr-TR,tr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
                # "cookie": "bcookie=3a6db8c0-6226-4d67-9b3c-39ee6fb7002b; EXP_ADP_RV_REORDER=A; EXP_ADP_RV_SEGMENT=B; run=43; D_LST=1; D_PDP=1; _gcl_au=1.1.515177829.1644933995; _ga=GA1.2.1857014358.1644933996; _gid=GA1.2.1588295387.1644933996; d_info=1536_864; N_S_A_W=1; N_A_P=1; GPAY_INTENT=1; D_HOM=1; N_CMS=0; PHPSESSID=041dvmhr4r3nqj0mt051pid5q0; disableSmartLogin=true; SHOW_PREVIEW_INFO_PAGE=false; OLD_LISTING_FLOW=false; GC_PREVIEW_EXPERIMENT=true; NEW_PRE_CONFIRMATION=true; C_AUTH=false; NEW_PAYMENT_PAGE=false; VIEW_COUPON_EXPERIMENT=true; NEW_ORDERLISTING_PAGE=true; NEW_ORDERDETAIL_PAGE=false; AMCVS_FE9A65E655E6E38A7F000101%40AdobeOrg=1; s_cc=true; frontendSource=react; pro=false; head_data_react={}; form_key=FFGAZIZcYSy6guaw; s_nr=1644987663041-Repeat; countryCode=TR; storeId=nykaa; lux_uid=164502537781396625; AMCV_FE9A65E655E6E38A7F000101%40AdobeOrg=-432600572%7CMCIDTS%7C19039%7CMCMID%7C81426820227033618243066641334787189520%7CMCAAMLH-1645633715%7C6%7CMCAAMB-1645633715%7CRKhpRz8krg2tLO6pguXWp5olkAcUniQYPHaMWWgdJ3xzPWQmdj0y%7CMCOPTOUT-1645036115s%7CNONE%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CvVersion%7C4.5.2; SITE_VISIT_COUNT=85; s_nr365=1645030255086-Repeat; cto_bundle=yZ-Tl19IZXRJdEFwYmJiRFlKdEUyRnMwdTJSYU8xanJLMjklMkJFZTdkSk1rZ2lobHFpRFU1RXRvNTFFOW5LM0x0NXE4RCUyQlk0eW5hZHklMkI1bjFIODFPeiUyQlljNXlUWnJSNTglMkJINU5LR1h6NlBVSWNROVNqNHZyazFBeVhiYzR0RSUyRmNiemQlMkYlMkJQMktDYlRiZ1pFbUVORlZoWERKbzFRJTNEJTNE; TS017d4a61=01317c4d00f4b4ecb9729e778b9c17dcf4ff9e0bde970f7d1b21ba9c6b22be6412bd39ff683b78cec4d5d72fa884218be5d8643776; TS5e83d05f027=08d3514ca6ab2000f82ea30abe3eacc9f428099d8668cb41a92cd2d81928f740933aee4731fd569b083d5530361130005c7a54f3c04dfcf2867d258ecec44f2412921fab91b839896e317f4c2953ff0d9fb3c2db28b8cfda2319bf9176d7af9f; s_sq=fsnecommerceprod%3D%2526c.%2526a.%2526activitymap.%2526page%253DNykaa%2526link%253DHair%252520Removal%252520Tools%2525202%2526region%253Dcustom-scroll%2526pageIDType%253D1%2526.activitymap%2526.a%2526.c%2526pid%253DNykaa%2526pidt%253D1%2526oid%253Dfunctioncn%252528%252529%25257B%25257D%2526oidt%253D2%2526ot%253DDIV",
                "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.82 Safari/537.36",
            }
            f_url = response.url.replace(
                f"page_no={page-1}", f"page_no={page}")
            print(f_url)
            print("*****************************************************")
            if f_url:
                yield Request(f_url, callback=self.jump, meta={"page": page+1}, headers=headersa)

    # 1. FOLLOWING
    def parse(self, response):
        item_loader = ListingLoader(response=response)
        external_link = response.url
        item_loader.add_value("external_link", response.url)
        main_cat = str(response.meta.get('main_cat'))
        sub_cat = str(response.meta.get('sub_cat'))
        child_cat = str(response.meta.get('child_cat'))

        title = response.xpath(
            "//script[contains(.,'window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ =')]/text()").get()
        if title:
            title = json.loads(title.split(
                "window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ")[-1])['productPage']['product']['name']
            if title:
                item_loader.add_value("title", title)

        price = response.xpath("//span[@class='css-12x6n3h']/text()").get()
        if price:
            price = price.split("₹")[-1]
            item_loader.add_value("price", price.split("₹")[-1])
        country = response.xpath(
            "//script[contains(.,'originOfCountryName')]/text()").get()
        if country:
            country = country.split("originOfCountryName")[1].split(
                ",")[0].replace('"', "").split(":")[-1].replace("\n", "").strip()
            item_loader.add_value('country', country)

        description = response.xpath(
            "//script[contains(.,'window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ =')]/text()").get()
        if description:
            description = json.loads(description.split(
                "window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ")[-1])['productPage']['product']['description']
            sel = Selector(text=description, type='html')
            if description:
                description = "".join(sel.xpath(".//p//text()").getall())
                item_loader.add_value("description", description)
            else:
                return []
        date = response.xpath(
            "//script[contains(.,'window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ =')]/text()").get()
        if date:
            date = json.loads(date.split(
                "window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ")[-1])['productPage']['product']['expiry']

            if date:
                item_loader.add_value('date', date)
            else:
                return []

        address = response.xpath(
            "//script[contains(.,'window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ =')]/text()").get()
        if address:
            address = json.loads(address.split(
                "window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ")[-1])['productPage']['product']['manufacturerAddress']
            if address:
                address = address.split(
                    "manufacturerAddress")[-1].split("}")[0].replace('"', "").split(":")[-1]
                item_loader.add_value(
                    'address', address.replace("\n", "").strip())
        importer = response.xpath(
            "//script[contains(.,'window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ =')]/text()").get()
        if importer:
            importer = json.loads(importer.split(
                "window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ")[-1])['productPage']['product']['manufacturerName']
            if importer:
                importer = importer.split(
                    "manufacturerAddress")[-1].split("}")[0].replace('"', "").split(":")[-1]
                item_loader.add_value(
                    'importer', importer.replace("\n", "").strip())

        yield{
            'address': address,
            'title': title,
            'description': description,
            'date': date,
            'importer': importer,
            'country': country,
            'main_cat': main_cat,
            'sub_cat': sub_cat,
            'child_cat': child_cat,
            # 'external_link':external_link
        }
```

***Now, This is the Output I'am receiving***

```
Finished in 0.001997700019273907 seconds
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2022-03-01 13:35:36 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\paart\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 192, in crawl
    return self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\paart\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 196, in _crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\paart\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1905, in unwindGenerator
    return _cancellableInlineCallbacks(gen)
  File "C:\Users\paart\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1815, in _cancellableInlineCallbacks
    _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, status)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "C:\Users\paart\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1660, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = current_context.run(gen.send, result)
  File "C:\Users\paart\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 88, in crawl
    start_requests = iter(self.spider.start_requests())
builtins.TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

2022-03-01 13:35:36 [twisted] CRITICAL:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\paart\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1660, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = current_context.run(gen.send, result)
  File "C:\Users\paart\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 88, in crawl
    start_requests = iter(self.spider.start_requests())
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
PS E:\Web Scraping - Nykaa (New_two)\couponsscraper\couponsscraper>
```

**Please, anyone, help me with this, where I'm going wrong, and if we not use 'threading' should we use 'snakeviz'.
Thanks**

Comment: Threading is not the answer. Have you tried to increase CONCURRENT_REQUESTS, CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN, CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP? Most probably you are being rate-limited.Have you tried using proxies

Comment: Okay, Actually, I have not used Proxies.

Comment: FYI: "Implement" is the wrong word. The implementor of `ThreadPoolExecutor` is the person or team that turned the _idea_ of `ThreadPoolExecutor` into a real thing that other people can use. You are asking how to _use_ Thread or ThreadPoolExecutor in your own implementation of a web site scraper. Unfortunately, that's not really the kind of question that this site is meant to answer. "How to use threads and thread pools" is at least a chapter in a book. How to do it right could be made into a whole book, or a whole semester at school.

Comment: @PaarthKothari As Upendra mentioned, scrapy already uses the Twisted Reactor, and so it's asynchronous and processes under concurrent requests already. You will have to change the concurrent requests as you're likely being rate limited. If anything, you could check out the latency of the downloaded requests, and the page you're on to identify a correlation in rate-limits. Then appropriately adjust